# What is Databricks Spark cluster manager? Can it be changed?

Tags: apache-spark, databricks, cluster-manager

Original Spark distributive supports several cluster managers like YARN, Mesos, Spark Standalone, K8s.
I can't find what is under the hood in Databricks Spark, which cluster manager it is using, and is it possible to change?

[image]

What's Databricks Spark architecture?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

You can't change the cluster manager in Databricks, and you really don't need that because this part is managed for you.   You can think about it as a kind of standalone cluster, but there are differences.  General Databricks architecture is shown [here](https://docs.databricks.com/getting-started/overview.html).

You can change the cluster configuration by different means - init scripts, configuration parameters, etc.  See [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/clusters/) for more details.